# Read file names that contain last 21 days

Tags: python, pyspark, wildcard, databricks

I have a parquet file name in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

The file names look like this:

```
dataset_2019_11_19-19.parquet
dataset_2020_01_19-20.parquet
dataset_2020_01_20-20.parquet
dataset_2020_01_21-20.parquet
dataset_2020_01_22-20.parquet
```

If I want to read all of the data for 2020, I would go about it this way, where I am using a wildcard to get anything after 2020:

```
datapath_v3_indata_imptp = "wasbs://mydata@mine.blob.core.windows.net/first_folder/dataset_2020*"
df_indata_v3_imptp=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load(datapath_v3_indata_imptp)
```

How would I get only last 21 days of data?

Comment: There are three possible approaches: 1) for every filename extract the date, and using `datetime` module parse them, then check if they're greater than `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=21)`; 2) generate dates for last 21 days (also using `datetime` module), convert them to strings and select only filenames containing those strings; 3) just create the date 21 days ago: `(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=21)).date().isoformat()` and then compare filenames - for ISO date format a greater string means a later date.

Comment: Thanks! It's not in the correct date format currently though so I would need to modify it. Sorry I am very new to Python so still learning

Comment: You can use `(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=21)).date().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')` to get the date in YYYY_MM_DD format, just like in your filenames.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible solution so I can test this out please? This is fantastic, just very new to Python and not even sure where to place the code you are suggesting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract date from the file_name using **`input_file_name()`** function then **`split`** + **`regexp_extract`**(to get only date) and finally **`to_date`** to create date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

- To filter use **`date_sub(current_date(),21)`** function to get 21 days prior date.

---

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#reading directory 
spark.read.parquet("wasbs://mydata@mine.blob.core.windows.net/first_folder/").\
withColumn("date",\
    to_date(\
        regexp_extract(\
            split(input_file_name(),"-")[0]\
            ,"_(.*)",1),\
        "yyyy_MM_dd")).\
filter(col("date") > date_sub(current_date(),21)).\
show(10,False)
```